# Magento 2: Product Edit page Error 503 PLEASE HELP

Tags: magento2, product, admin

When I try to add or edit a product,  I get blank page with **Error 503: Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.**

In the past 2 month I have created a lot of extensions and all are working fine. The products are shown in the product grid, no problems.

All modules in Admin are working, a maintanance.flag file does not exist.
I disabled all my new modules, nothing works, I am not able to add or edit a product. I dont know what to do, we would like to start next week with our shop.

PLEASE, PLEASE HELP.

Christian

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Server error log files? i mean apache or nginx error files?
maybe you can find something useful.

Comment: I checked them, there are items like:main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notice
or
 main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_3942059a62c87af8724fe1ef3f757dc31 and handles default, catalog_product_attribute_index: Please correct the XML data and try again. 
I dont know what they mean

Comment: i suppose that you have already check and the server capacity.

Comment: Another item in log file is:
main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.product.edit.tab.grouped.container' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist

Comment: Yes I checked the capacity, everything is fine, and it worked in the past without problem

Comment: christian where did you find these errors? I mean the files are inside magento var directory?

Comment: Yes, in system.log and exception.log. Thats the first time that I have checked log-files, and I dont know, if these are the right files to look.
What I dont understand is: The product grid is shown without problem, but the edit page make this error, the rest is running without problems

Comment: You have to check the web server error log files. It is possible to find something that may help you. if you have SSH access check /var/log/nginx/error.log or /var/log/apache/error.log

Comment: Iam working with Putty. How can I check these files. Sorry for my questions

Comment: The error is already shown, when I try to add a product. What I mean is: When a product should be added, the attribute-set selection is shown at first, but I get immediately the 503 error. I have added a lot of Attribute Sets the last 2 month, can this be the problem?

Comment: navigate to /var/log folder. there are folders with error log files. usually are the following nginx, httpd, apache

Comment: maybe but if you dont find the error exactly, you will never know.

Comment: Currently I am in my file-system (with Filezilla). In my var/log folder, I have only system.log, exception.log and debug.log

Comment: That would be really bad, it would mean, that I have to set up the whole shop again

Comment: UPDATE: Thanks to all for your help! I tried everything, I have disabled all my extensions....nothing worked. I have decided to reinstall Magento.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many error notifications in the web technology & in the server status notification one of them is as follows:

```
503 Service Unavailable Error
```

This errors mostly comes when there is some maintenance work going on into the server & other than that mostly when the server is too busy & not able to respond to the request.

There can be so many possibilities for this but in Magento as per my observation this error comes when we are having some code issue that is when we have invoked any method which requires so much time to respond or when we have printed an object or something with very huge content of data.

To trace this you can take the following steps:

- Please check your log files.
- Please enable/allow the error message to be shown on the front-end. To do this put the below code into your `index.php` file present at your root as well as present in your `pub` directory.

Code to be placed in **index.php**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

> Note: Make sure you are in the developer mode because if you are in
>   production mode it is possible then also it will not show any error
>   message on the front-end. Please re deploy your site with the
>   following commands from the command prompt/terminal.
>
> ```
> php bin/magento maintenance:enable
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> php bin/magento maintenance:disabled
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

Comment: Thank your for your help. I just trying int

Comment: One of the items in debug.log is the follow:
main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE0_36f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.

Comment: And: main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE0_34f4b93930d5c5a39a62d760572cf3b89 and handles default, catalog_product_edit, catalog_product_grouped: Please correct the XML data and try again.

Comment: I dont know where and which XML data I must correct?????

Comment: are you able to see any error in the browser after enabling the error message? & other thing is that are you in a developer mode?

Comment: No, no errors are displayed in the browser, and yes, I'm in the developer mode. Nothing works :-(

Comment: delete the generated folder & run this command -> `php bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv` & see if any error appears.

Comment: Same error as before